# Working with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type using a plugin. Now, I want to display the post in the home page through my custom home page template. I handcoded the image and text in the template and styled it with css, and it's showing fine. But, I want to be able to change the image and text from admin backend and it will dynamically reflect on the homepage.

Here my [Website.](http://www.savelifeafricanmedicalmission.org/)

The section before footer is what I'm referring to. I want the image, title and text to output dynamically when changed from backend.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this for a project I'm working on and I found this:
[Displaying custom post types](https://www.proteusthemes.com/blog/displaying-custom-post-types-templates-querying/).

Hope this helps.